# Is there any way to make a ModuleScript run the same as regular code?

Tags: module, lua, roblox

So I want to write a module into another script, would it be possible to do this by setting the environment to the thread level using this line 
`local __={};setmetatable(__,{__index=_G});setfenv(0,__);` is this even possible? Or am I severely misunderstanding setfenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the environment would basically change the current definitions of most global variables.

For example, if you did

```
setfenv(0, {});
```

You would not be able to use a lot of built-in functions, including 'setfenv, print, warn, error, etc, etc, etc'.

Though, if in the table that sefenv needs as argument, instead of putting in a empty table, you put something like

```
setfenv(0, {["print"] = print, ["kek"] = function() print("hi") end}); -- We can define 'print' to 'print' here because we are defining things in the table before the environment is set.
```

And then, if you did

```
kek();
```

Your console would be:

```
script: 'hi'
```

Following this logic, yes, you would be able to set the environment of your script to the environment of the ModuleScript to use it's functions, but it would be easier and I think more effective to simply do

```
api = require(module);
api.kek();
```

Anyway, both are correct, but the second one can be easier. Hope my answer helps!